# Making a gym application

Tags: python, sql, database, tkinter

whoever sees this, I am currently in the midst of making a Gym program for a high school project that requires python and databases, except my knowledge of python is very small. I can use SQL but I'm having trouble understanding how to connect my GUIs and making the entry fields insert data into the database. I will insert what I've done so far, bless the poor soul who sees this monstrosity :). This is also my first time doing a stack overflow question, so if you can, please bear with me.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

#=============DB Connection

with sqlite3.connect('gym 4.db') as db:
    c = db.cursor()
db.commit()
db.close()    
#===================== Sign Up page
def signup():
    import tkinter
    global window2
    window2=tkinter.Tk()
    window2.title('Sign Up Page')
    window2.geometry('400x400')

    option_Menu = tkinter.StringVar(window2)
    options = ("Gender","Male","Female")
    menu = tkinter.OptionMenu(window2,option_Menu,*options)
    menu.grid(row=7,column=2)
    option_Menu.set("Gender")
    selection=option_Menu.get()

    lb6= Label(window2, text='First Name')
    lb6.grid(row=1, column=1)
    lb7= Label(window2, text='Last Name')
    lb7.grid(row=3, column=1)
    lb8= Label(window2, text='Password')
    lb8.grid(row=5, column=1)
    lb9= Label(window2, text='Gender')
    lb9.grid(row=7, column=1)
    lb10= Label(window2, text='Email Address')
    lb10.grid(row=9, column=1)
    lb11= Label(window2, text='Age')
    lb11.grid(row=11, column=1)
    lb12= Label(window2, text='DOB')
    lb12.grid(row=13, column=1)
    lb13= Label(window2, text='Address')
    lb13.grid(row=15, column=1)
    lb14= Label(window2, text='Phone')
    lb14.grid(row=17, column=1)
    lb15= Label(window2, text='Remember me')
    lb15.grid(row=19, column=1)

    b4= Button(window2, text='Sign Up', command=home_screen)

    b4.grid(row=21, column=2)
    FirstName_text= StringVar()
    e6= Entry(window2, textvariable= FirstName_text)
    e6.grid(row=1, column=2)
    LastName_text= StringVar()
    e7= Entry(window2, textvariable= LastName_text)
    e7.grid(row=3, column=2)
    Password_text= StringVar()
    e8= Entry(window2, textvariable= Password_text)
    e8.grid(row=5, column=2)
    EmailAddress_text= StringVar()
    e9= Entry(window2, textvariable= EmailAddress_text)
    e9.grid(row=9, column=2)
    Age_text= IntVar()
    e10= Entry(window2, textvariable= Age_text)
    e10.grid(row=11, column=2)
    DOB_text= IntVar()
    e11= Entry(window2, textvariable= DOB_text)
    e11.grid(row=13, column=2)
    Address_text= StringVar()
    e12= Entry(window2, textvariable= Address_text)
    e12.grid(row=15, column=2)
    Phone_text= IntVar()
    e13= Entry(window2, textvariable= Phone_text)
    e13.grid(row=17, column=2)
    RMe_text= IntVar()
    e14= Checkbutton(window2, variable=RMe_text)
    e14.grid(row= 19, column=2)


#Main option page
def main_screen():

    global main
    main = Tk()

    main.title("Joe's Gym Menu")
    main.geometry('400x400')

    Button(main, text='Sign up', command=signup).pack()

#Gym homepage (Going to include a OptionMenu for classes and a button which makes a window that pops up showing current classes)
def home_screen():
    global home
    home = Tk()
    home.title("Joe's Gym Home")
    home.geometry('400x400')

    b6 = Button(home, text='Logout', command=main_screen)
    b6.grid(row=10, column=1)

   main_screen()
```

Comment: It would help if you reduced the code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with understanding how to get data out of an entry widget and into a database, that can be replicated with a single entry widget and a simple database, and enough code to glue them together. We don't need nearly 175 lines of code.

Comment: you need button which runs function which gets data from Entry and use it in SQL - but it seems you assign to button function which doesn't get values from Entry but it opens different window with different entries for different use. BTW: you will have problem with local variables which are not available in other functions.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll use this advice to fix up my code, I just thought that I'd need to put my entire code down because most of it requires the other definitions to work, my bad.